# OpenLayers 6.0.1 set custom center after load map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers 6.0.1 web map. I have plot a new marker on map with custom image and want to put the map to be centered newly plotted marker position.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the docs: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#setCenter

Answer (score 3):

You can put a feature on map and fit him

```
 var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector()
  });
  var marker = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-44,-2]))
  });
  vectorLayer.getSource().addFeature(marker)
  console.log(vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures())


  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),vectorLayer
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
      zoom: 4
    })
  });
  var extent = vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent();
  map.getView().fit(extent,map.getSize())
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you have already added the marker on the map this means you already have the coordinates of that Marker. Note that a marker is just a Point feature with a specific Icon style which needs a coordinate set that fits your projection. In order to center the map on the marker you have just created, you can do the following:

I guess you are using an EPSG:3857 projection on your map and that you have coordinates in EPSG:4326 which is very usual.

```
     let marker = new Feature({
        geometry: new Point(fromLonLat([38.71, 88.66]))
     });
     marker.setStyle(new Style({
            image: Icon({
                  anchor: [0, 0],
                  src: 'yourimage.png'
               })
           }));

     let vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
          source: new VectorSource({
             features: [marker]
       })
     });
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    map.getView().animate({zoom: 5, center: fromLonLat([38.71, 98.66])});
```

Of course, there is plenty of output ommited in this example, but I'm posting it just to give you an idea of how you can animate your viewport to a specific location. Most of the mentioned code and imports should already exist in your project so you just need to grab the coordinates and animate the map.

Answer (score 0):

I have got answer from 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51207211/openlayer-load-map-with-initial-marker

```
<h2>Location Map</h2>
  <div id="mapLat"></div>
    <div id="mapLon"></div>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var mapId = "map";
    var lat,lon;
function createMap() {
    var queryString = window.location.search;
    queryString = queryString.substring(1);
    var queries = queryString.split("$");
    var Qstring = [];
    for(i=0;i<queries.length;i++)
    {
        var temp = queries[i].split('=');
        //stack.push(temp[0]);
        Qstring.push(temp[0]);
    }
    lat = Qstring[0];
    lon = Qstring[1];
    document.getElementById('mapLat').innerHTML = 'Latitude:' + lat;
    document.getElementById('mapLon').innerHTML = 'Longtiude:' + lon;

  var coordinate = [lon, lat];
  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({});
  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
  });
  var view = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat(coordinate),
    zoom: 10,
    maxZoom: 19,
    minZoom: 5
  });
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM({
        key: 'myKey',
        crossOrigin: ''
      })
    }), vectorLayer, ],
    target: document.getElementById(mapId),
    controls: ol.control.defaults(),
    view: view
  });
  // create custom marker image with custom text in bottom
  var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [12, 37],
      anchorXUnits: 'pixels', //'fraction'
      anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
      opacity: 0.8,
      //src: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png'
      src: 'img/pin/location_pin.gif'
    })
  });

  var marker;
  this.setMarker = function(coordinate) {
    marker = new ol.Feature(
      new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(coordinate))
    );
    marker.setStyle(iconStyle);
    vectorSource.addFeature(marker);
  }
  return this;
}

var map = createMap();
map.setMarker([lon, lat])
    </script>
```